# how do i know on which drive my ubuntu is installed on?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation, hard-drive, ssd

I had a pc with **one TB hdd** , then I got **128gb ssd** for it ,
then I removed windows 10 and installed ubuntu
but now I am confused on which drive my ubuntu is installed.
I want it to be on ssd

gparted screenshots for ssd:

[image: gparted screenshots for ssd]

gparted screenshot for hdd:

[image: gparted screenshot for hdd]

Comment: see the `/` mountpoint noted in image 1? That is a linux or unix main partition ;)

Answer (score 3):

Open a terminal and type

`$ lsblk -ape7 -o+MODEL` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

There a `/` will appear under mountpoint,
this generally is where you have your OS installed.

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
findmnt /
```

will give you the desired information.